# Windows cannot access Samba after changing password

Tags: ubuntu, windows, password, samba

I have a samba server setup in Ubuntu 18.04 and have multiple users with their own respective folder to access with their credentials. Right after a user changes his/her samba password the users cannot log into the samba share without restarting the computer or clearing out the cache.

Can it be configured from somewhere in the samba server that the user credentials are not cached in the Windows machines?

Comment: windoze is windoze, and no linux system is going to tell it what to do with its cache :p

Comment: @Bravo not a great insight, seeing that other server implementations seem to have no such problem, so there's definitely some way of telling the Windows client to use the right password (or maybe it's doing that and the samba server isn't? Who knows.)

Comment: Very interesting question. I have this issue too. Have you read https://serverfault.com/q/451387 and https://www.top-password.com/blog/clear-saved-credentials-for-network-share-or-remote-desktop/? May be it helps.